# Conclude that $Z_n$ converges in probability to zero.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I really don't know how to show all the convergence. I know the definitions but I don't know how to apply them. For the second part I found this proposition to use "$X_n$ converse in $L^1$ to X $\implies \mathbb{E}[X_n] - \mathbb{E}[X] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n -X|] \to 0$

The exercise: 
Let $\lambda$ > 0 and let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables, such that, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$\mathbb{P}(X_n =k) = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k/k!$

We define the sequence $Z_n$ of random variables as $Z_n = \prod_{m=1}^n X_m$.

1. Compute $\mathbb{P}(Z_n \ne 0)$, conclude that $Z_n$ converge in probability to zero.
2. Does one have almost sure convergence? Does one have convergence in $L^1$?

If somebody can help it would be very nice.

Comment: I have posted  a brief answer. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i used the script, so it was a perfect answer, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: $ P(Z_n\neq 0)\leq (P(X_i\geq 1))^{n} =(1-e^{-\lambda})^{n} \to 0$. Hence $Z_n \to 0$ in probability. Also $\sum_n P(Z_n\neq 0) <\infty$ since $\sum r^{n} <\infty$ for $0 \leq r <1$. By Borel - Cantelli Lemma we see that $Z_n =0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, with probability $1$,  so $Z_n \to 0$ almost surely. Also $EZ_n=(EX_1)^{n}=\lambda ^{n}$ so $Z_n$ tends to $0$ in $L^{1}$ iff $\lambda <1$.